# CMake: opengl include dirs are named differently on different platforms

Tags: opengl, include, cmake

Cmake founds include directory for opengl, but opengl headers are in a subdirectory that is named differently on different platforms (and, maybe, compilers): gl on Windows, GL on Linux, OpenGL (as far as I know) on Mac. Thus, adding OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY to include paths doesn't help very much - I still have to include  (or ,  and so on) in my sources.
How should I deal with it?

Comment: Did you try the command `find_package(OpenGL)`? I don't understand from your question you already did or not.

Comment: Of course I did. Without that the OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY variable would be empty.

Comment: Ok, my bad, I wasn't sure. Then, I don't think there is any generic method besides forcing users to rename their directories. But I find it strange though: I have only seen the `GL` directory, whatever the operating system.

Comment: At least I am sure about "gl" on Windows and "GL" on Linux. There's a solution to write something like the FindOpenGL module for CMake, but it's ugly because it will do almost what this module actually does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you mean `OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR`, not `OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY`.

You have a couple of choices here.  The simplest is to add `${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}/GL` or `${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}/OpenGL` to your include search paths and use

```
#include "gl.h"
```

in your source code.

The case of filenames is disregarded on Windows, so you don't need to use `/gl` *and* `/GL` - simply `/GL` will do.

To achieve this, in your CMakeLists.txt do:

```
if(APPLE)
  include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}/OpenGL)
else()
  include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}/GL)
endif()
```

To make this a bit more robust, you can have CMake find the path to "gl.h" and include that:

```
find_path(OpenglIncludeSubdir
            NAMES gl.h
            PATHS ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}
            PATH_SUFFIXES GL OpenGL
            NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
include_directories(${OpenglIncludeSubdir})
```

Again, in your source you'd use:

```
#include "gl.h"
```

Possibly the most robust (i.e. avoiding further include paths beyond `${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}`) would be to find the path to "gl.h" and then use [`configure_file`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aconfigure_file) to apply the correct `#include` term.  You would use an input file which contained something like:

```
#include "@OpenglSubdir@/gl.h"
```

and then running `configure_file` would replace `@OpenglSubdir@` with its value and write the contents to an output file.  This output file would then be included in your target and would have

```
#include "GL/gl.h"
```

or

```
#include "OpenGL/gl.h"
```

as appropriate.

To achieve this, you'd do something like:

```
find_file(OpenglSubdir
            NAMES GL OpenGL
            PATHS ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}
            NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
get_filename_component(OpenglSubdir ${OpenglSubdir} NAME)
configure_file(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_config.h.in ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_config.h)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems that I have plenty of solutions now :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems this won't work with Windows, as CMake apparently doesn't set `OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR` on Windows. This seems to be a deliberate decision, based on [this Sept. 2004 mailing list post](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2004-September/005508.html), and it appears that that has not changed in the intervening decade.